# How to fetch all records from a embadded documnet from Mongodb

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

i am trying to query all the records from a repo from Mongodb. using JPQL query but it give the error that i have listed below. as i have manytoone relationship.

have tried

```
String query = "select g From AnalyticsGoal g JOIN g.analyticsMethods";
List<AnalyticsGoal> analyticsGoals = em.createQuery(query, AnalyticsGoal.class).getResultList();

public List<AnalyticsGoal> getAllAnalyticsGoals() {
     String query = "select g From AnalyticsGoal g JOIN g.analyticsMethods";
     List<AnalyticsGoal> analyticsGoals = em.createQuery(query, AnalyticsGoal.class).getResultList();
     return analyticsGoals;
}
```

Error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unknown wrap conversion requested: java.lang.String to java.lang.String
```

Comment: Can you share the full error log and  the AnalyticsGoal class code? What line the error happened?

Comment: The problem is resolved. the error i was getting because of the document in database. one data was inserted as an array instead of string. I have just migrate the data from SQL to NoSQL and i didnt even looked in it. but thanks for your quick response.